# the arithmetic order in C programming

Tags: c, algorithm, variables, math

Today as I am trying to solve a simple 2-dimensional math function using C. However the result I got is kinda funny there. Code is here:

```
int main()
{
    int x, y;

    x = 10 - y;
    y = x - 2;
    printf("the x and y would be %d, %d ", x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

So as you can see, the answer would be easily calculated out as `x=6` and `y=4` but the program listed above gives me `x=8` and `y=6`. It seems like the program somehow got `y`'s value as `6` first and then ignores the first equation and directly put `6` in the second equation then get `x` value. Kinda hilarious to see this tho. Hope somebody can explain the reason to me!

Comment: Your code has undefined behaviour: `y` has no value!

Comment: Missing `;` on the `x=` line.

Comment: @KerrekSB but how? I did the same thing to both x and y I think...

Comment: @xxbbcc oh I forgot that. But I don't think that's where the problem is

Comment: @user1579701: In the line `x = 10 - y;` you are attempting to give `x` a value, but you fail, because in doing so you are trying to evaluate the expression `10 - y`, in which `y` has no value. This means your program has *undefined behaviour*, and therefore nothing about it can be said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C language does not solve equations. There's no such feature in the language. C language evaluates expressions.

Since you never initialized your variables, both `x` and `y` initially contain garbage values. Your very first expression `x = 10 - y` means: subtract garbage value from `10` and store it in `x`.

The fact that your `y` began its life with a garbage value of `2` in it (giving you `8` in `x`) is just a random coincidence. I'm actually surprised you got such a nice-looking garbage value in it. Usually it is something much more horrible.

Comment: ohh, looks like I made a big mistake here. Thanks for the explanation very much! I now understand this.

Comment: It looks like `y` started out as 2.  I don't know if that helps some C master figure out why it started that way instead of something horrible.

Answer (score 5):

The reason is a basic misunderstanding of an imperative programming language. The C language is not an equation solver. '=' means an assignment, not an equation.

Comment: so should I replace all `=` signs into `==`? or this equation is not actually acceptable in C...

Comment: @user1579701 This is not possible to do in C.  (Well, it would be *possible*, but it would involve a lot of work and not two simple equations.)